# Grouping the data from a column using awk or any other shell command

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I could format the data using a perl script (hash). I am wondering if it can be done through some shell one liner, so that every time I dont need to write a perl script if there is some change in the
input format.
Example Input:

```
rinku   a
rinku   b
rinku   c
rrs     d
rrs     e
abc     f
abc     g
abc     h
abc     i
xyz     j
```

example Output:

```
rinku  a,b,c
rrs    d,e
abc    f,g,h,i
xyz    j
```

Please help me with a command using shell/awk/sed  to format the input.

Thanks,
Rinku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `awk` program also has associative arrays, similar to Perl:

```
awk '{v[$1]=v[$1]","$2}END{for(k in v)print k" "substr(v[k],2)}' inputFile
```

For each line `X Y` (key of `X`, value of `Y`), it basically just appends `,Y` to every array element indexed by `X`, taking advantage of the fact they all start as empty strings.

Then, since your values are then of the form `,x,y,z`, you just strip off the first character when outputting.

This generates, for your input data (in `inputFile`):

```
rinku a,b,c
abc f,g,h,i
rrs d,e
xyz j
```

---

As an aside, if you want it as nicely formatted as the original, you can create a `program.awk` file:

```
{
    val[$1] = val[$1]","$2
    if (length ($1) > maxlen) {
        maxlen = length ($1)
    }
}
END {
    for (key in val) {
        printf "%-*s %s\n", maxlen, key, substr(val[key],2)
    }
}
```

and run that with:

```
awk -f program.awk inputFile
```

and you'll get:

```
rinku a,b,c
abc   f,g,h,i
rrs   d,e
xyz   j
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
$ awk '{arr[$1]=arr[$1]?arr[$1]","$2:$2} END{for (i in arr) print i, arr[i]}' input
rinku a,b,c
abc f,g,h,i
rrs d,e
xyz j
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n ':cycle
   $!N
   s/^\([^[:blank:]]*\)\([[:blank:]]\{1,\}.*\)\n\1[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/\1\2,/;t cycle
   P
   s/.*\n//;t cycle' YourFile
```

trying not to use the hold buffer (and not loading the full file in memory)
 - load the line
 - if first word is the same as the one after CR, repolace the CR and first word by a `,`
 - if the case, restart at line loading
 - if not, print first line
 - replace the current buffer until first `\n` by nothing
 - if the case restart at line loading

posix version so `--posix` on GNU sed